# How to fix flex-1 is not working in react native?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I'm new to react native and following the tutorial on youtube. When I'm developing the tutorial app there is a place to add flex-1 as a className. But after adding it nothing happened.
This is the tutorial:- https://youtu.be/AkEnidfZnCU

**This is my code**

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { UserIcon, ChevronDownIcon, MagnifyingGlassIcon, AdjustmentsHorizontalIcon } from "react-native-heroicons/outline";

const HomeScreen = () => {

    const navigation = useNavigation();
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerShown: false,
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <SafeAreaView className="bg-white pt-5">
            <Text className="text-red-500">
                {/* Header */}
                <View className="flex-row pb-3 items-center mx-4 space-x-2 px-4">
                    <Image
                        source={{
                            uri: 'https://links.papareact.com/wru',
                        }}
                        className="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-300 p-4 rounded-full"
                    />
                    <View className="flex-1">
                        <Text className="font-bold text-gray-400 text-xs">Deliver Now!</Text>
                        <Text className="font-bold text-xl">Current Location
                            <ChevronDownIcon size={20} color="#00CCBB" />
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <UserIcon size={35} color="#00CCBB" />
                </View>
                {/* Search box */}
                <View className="flex-row items-center space-x-2 pb-2 mx-4 px-4">
                    <View className="flex-row space-x-2 bg-gray-200 p-3">
                        <MagnifyingGlassIcon size={20} color="gray" />
                        <TextInput placeholder='Restaurant and cuisines' keyboardType='default' />
                    </View>
                    <AdjustmentsHorizontalIcon color="#00CCBB" />
                </View>
            </Text>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

**This is how it looks like**

[image: This is how it looks like]

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

==> Try this may be it works. You have to add `View` with `flex-1`

```
 return (
        <SafeAreaView className="bg-white pt-5">
           <View className="flex-1"> // here
            <Text className="text-red-500">
                {/* Header */}
                <View className="flex-row pb-3 items-center mx-4 space-x-2 px-4">
                    <Image
                        source={{
                            uri: 'https://links.papareact.com/wru',
                        }}
                        className="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-300 p-4 rounded-full"
                    />
                    <View className="flex-1">
                        <Text className="font-bold text-gray-400 text-xs">Deliver Now!</Text>
                        <Text className="font-bold text-xl">Current Location
                            <ChevronDownIcon size={20} color="#00CCBB" />
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <UserIcon size={35} color="#00CCBB" />
                </View>
                {/* Search box */}
                <View className="flex-row items-center space-x-2 pb-2 mx-4 px-4">
                    <View className="flex-row space-x-2 bg-gray-200 p-3">
                        <MagnifyingGlassIcon size={20} color="gray" />
                        <TextInput placeholder='Restaurant and cuisines' keyboardType='default' />
                    </View>
                    <AdjustmentsHorizontalIcon color="#00CCBB" />
                </View>
            </Text>
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
```

Comment: I tried it. but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `<Text className="text-red-500">`, like this:

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView className="bg-white pt-5">
            {/* Header */}
            <View className="flex-row pb-3 items-center mx-4 space-x-2 px-4">
                <Image
                    source={{
                        uri: 'https://links.papareact.com/wru',
                    }}
                    className="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-300 p-4 rounded-full"
                />
                <View className="flex-1">
                    <Text className="font-bold text-gray-400 text-xs">Deliver Now!</Text>
                    <Text className="font-bold text-xl">Current Location
                        <ChevronDownIcon size={20} color="#00CCBB" />
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <UserIcon size={35} color="#00CCBB" />
            </View>
            {/* Search box */}
            <View className="flex-row items-center space-x-2 pb-2 mx-4 px-4">
                <View className="flex-row space-x-2 bg-gray-200 p-3">
                    <MagnifyingGlassIcon size={20} color="gray" />
                    <TextInput placeholder='Restaurant and cuisines' keyboardType='default' />
                </View>
                <AdjustmentsHorizontalIcon color="#00CCBB" />
            </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
);
```